# Find multiple of n in array. (In this case at least 4 times the number 1)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm following a challenge on a certain website (not for job employment or school, just to get better) and am stuck on this problem.

The problem wants me to sort blocks with sizes 4x1, 3x1, 2x1, 1x1 and create a 4x4 field square with those blocks.

Blocks come in shape of an array with 1-4 representing block size.
e.g blocks[2,2,1,3,4] and my task is to return a boolean for each array, stating whether it's possible or not.

I'm done determening it for most blocks, the last thing I need is creating a conditional or regex that shows me whether there are still 4 1s in the array left to build a row of four.
My approach is shown in the code section.

I've tried looping over the array to get the amount of ones (or just the multiple of n to stay mathematic) by holding a counter and resetting the counter afterwards.

Exemplary here is how I check whether there are 3x1 blocks and a 1x1 block to finish a row for my 4x4. The only thing I want to create is 4 rows of a combination of the aforementioned blocks. eg 2x1 + 2x1 = 4x1, 4* 4x1 = 4x4

```
//if this block is a 3x1 and there is a 1x1 still left in the array
if(blocks[i] === 3 && blocks.indexOf(1) !== -1) {
    blocks[i] = 0;
    blocks[blocks.indexOf(1)] = 0;
    //remove those values from the array and add a row
    rowCounter++;
}
```

This goes on in an unsightly and huge if else block, but I don't know how else to do it and that's not part of the issue.

In the end, the function returns whether rowCounter is >= 4

To understand in and output easier, here is the tester:

```
Test.describe('Sample Tests ~ should pass all the tests provided', _ => {
    Test.assertEquals(buildSquare([3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2]), false)
    Test.assertEquals(buildSquare([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), true)
    Test.assertEquals(buildSquare([3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4]), false)
    Test.assertEquals(buildSquare([4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1]), true)
    Test.assertEquals(buildSquare([1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]), false)
});
```

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of an input and the expected output?

Comment: Sure, the input is an array varying in size that contains the size of blocks.
e.g blocks[2,2,1,4,3,1,1,1,1,3] -- easier visualized as a plane [2x1,2x1,1x1,4x1, and so on]] and the output is true or false.
Again: The task is to take those blocks and see if I can create a 4 x 4 square with it.

Comment: So `[2,1,1]` returns true and `[4,1]` is false? What about 2 blocks like `[4,2,1,1]`? You need to post a solid example of an input and output ***in the question***

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:regex]?

Comment: I tagged it with regex because I had hoped someone could give me a regex along the lines of /1{4}/g or sth that returns me 4x 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count how many rows you can build: like fours, threes+ones, pairs of twos, a two and a pair of ones, quadruplets of ones

If I can build at least 4 rows like that, I'm good.

```js
function buildSquare(arr) {
  let [, ones, twos, threes, fours] = arr.reduce((acc, v) => (acc[v]++, acc), Array(5).fill(0)),
    n = Math.min(threes, ones),
    rows = fours + n + Math.floor(twos / 2);

  ones -= n;
  if ((twos%2 === 1) && Math.floor(ones / 2)) {
    ++rows;
    ones -= 2;
  }
  return 4 <= rows + Math.floor(ones / 4);
}

console.log(buildSquare([3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 2]), false);
console.log(buildSquare([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]), true);
console.log(buildSquare([3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4]), false);
console.log(buildSquare([4, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1]), true);
console.log(buildSquare([1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1]), false);
```

and a quicker version:

```
function buildSquare(arr) {
  let counts = Array(4).fill(0);
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) counts[arr[i] - 1]++;
  let n = Math.min(counts[2], counts[0]),
    rows = counts[3] + n + (counts[1] >> 1);

  if(4 <= rows) return true;

  counts[0] -= n;
  if ((counts[1] & 1) && (counts[0] >> 1)) {
    ++rows;
    counts[0] -= 2;
  }
  return 4 <= rows + (counts[0] >> 2);
}
```

Comment: woah. I like that first solution a lot, but don't necessarily understand the syntax in all of it:
why declare let [, ones, twos] starting with a comma?
Also .. if it isn't too much of a bother
How does that big funky reduce work?

Comment: @milkychocolatepoodle They are both the same solution, only the second code is faster, because it doesn't use all these new fancy JS features. *"why declare let [, ones, twos] starting with a comma?"* because I don't care about the `zeroes`, so I don't even need to declare a variable for that. The reduce iterates over the array and returns an Array with the counts for `[zeroes, ones, twos, threes, fours]`; Edit: In the second snippet I've completely eliminated the zeroes, but now the indices are confusing, as `v[0]` contains the ones, `v[1]` contains the twos, ...